# error 500 in Back Office when using a woocommerce function in functions.php

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to display the number of items in the cart in my main navigation menu.

I added this to the functions.php of my child theme, but I can't access Appearances/menu Back office anymore.

Any idea what's wrong ?
I am stuck, as you can see I've tried several syntaxes.

Just using $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count(); makes the appearances/menu page blank with an error 500.

Thanks

```
add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item','my_item_setup' );
function my_item_setup($item) {

    if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) ) {

        global $woocommerce;

        ?>
        <pre><?php var_dump( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents_count()  ); ?></pre>

        <?php

        if ( $item->url == esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ) ) {

            //$item->title = 'MY BAG('. '<span class="count">' .  wp_kses_data( sprintf( _n( '%d', '%d', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(), 'simple-shop' ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ) ) . '</span>)';

            $item->title = 'MY BAG('. '<span class="count">' .  wp_kses_data( sprintf( _n( '%d', '%d', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count();, 'simple-shop' ), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count(); ) ) . '</span>)';

            //$item->title = 'MY BAG('. '<span class="count">' .  $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents_count() . '</span>)';

            //$item->title = sprintf( _n( '%d', '%d', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count();, 'simple-shop' ), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count(); );

        }
    }
    return $item;
}
```

Comment: There is probably an error_log / php_errorlog file somewhere with the exact error. We'd need that before looking at code

Comment: the line not commented out above has ";"s where there shouldn't be...

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the ';'. @PaulG I am going to try and find the error log.